# How to add a label to the ticker on two side by side plots in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
upper       lower     average
12          9         10
6           3         5
```

from this code:

```
upperlimit = c(right00, right20)
lowerlimit = c(left00, left20)
mean = c(mean(pm00), mean(pm20))
df = data.frame(cbind(upperlimit, lowerlimit, mean))
```

I have been able to use ggplot2 in R to create (I put the c(1,2) as I wasn't sure what else to do to make it two columns):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=c(1,2), y=average))+
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
theme()
```

[image]

I would like to remove the 1.0 and 2.0 tickers on the xlabel and have them read "Interval 1" and "Interval 2".

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to just put `c("interval 1", "interval 2")` instead of `c(1, 2)` for the x aesthetic.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=c("interval 1", "interval 2"), y=average))+
geom_point() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
theme()
```

[image]